# Vaadin recognizes different browser sizes from different applications but the device is the same

Tags: java, vaadin, screen-resolution, vaadin7

I took the [Vaadin Dashboard Demo](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo) and build another app from it. The component trees of the two apps are the same, as well as the themes and their stylesheets.

If I resize the desktop browser I get the responsive behaviour that I expect, but when I access from a mobile browser (Chrome on the Nexus 5) I get different behaviours:
[image: Custom app vs Dashboard]

Adding these lines to the end of the `init()` method of the two `UI`s

```
public class MyAppUI extends UI {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        ...
        final Page page = Page.getCurrent();
        System.out.println(page.getWebBrowser().getBrowserApplication());
        System.out.println("Resolution: " + page.getBrowserWindowWidth() + "x" + page.getBrowserWindowHeight());
    }
}

public class DashboardUI extends UI {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        ...
        final Page page = Page.getCurrent();
        System.out.println(page.getWebBrowser().getBrowserApplication());
        System.out.println("Resolution: " + page.getBrowserWindowWidth() + "x" + page.getBrowserWindowHeight());
    }
}
```

I get for my app:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/MMB29S) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.83 Mobile Safari/537.36
Resolution: 980x1394
```

and for the Vaadin Dashboard:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/MMB29S) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.83 Mobile Safari/537.36
Resolution: 360x512
```

Since my app works on resized desktop browser I'm sure it will work if only it can get the same browser size of the Dashboard.

It doesn't make sense to me, someone else got this problem? If you need additional information please comment and I'll edit the question.

Comment: It seems the first screenshot is taken on some desktop version, and the second on the mobile one (note the icon on the left collapsed into the hamburger) - so more of a client-side thing. Can you explore the tree via some browser inspector and tell what are the differences? You should especially watch for things that affect CSS media queries

Comment: please check, if your copy there actually injects this html properly: https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/blob/b9749203291bc5e485ed59d40433e809547a036d/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/DashboardSessionInitListener.java#L24-L27

Comment: @cfrick was it! If you want to post the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mobile browsers need some ceremonial boilerplate in the `viewport` meta header.

See https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/blob/b9749203291bc5e485ed59d40433e809547a036d/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/DashboardSessionInitListener.java#L24-L27 for how it is done in the project, you mentioned as your base.

> ```
> head.appendElement("meta")
>         .attr("name", "viewport")
>         .attr("content",
>                 "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no");
> ```

Comment: for future references: You can also use this annotation on your UI class:
@Viewport("user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0")